# Items from array using .map() into a group of options

Tags: jquery

I have an array that is created using jquery .map():

```
var options = $('#' + id + ' option'); //Id of select that is generated dynamically
        values = $.map(options, function(option) {
            return [
                option.value,
                option.text
            ];
        });
```

This creates an array of `"03","rents", "04", "other income"` etc.  When I attempt to put these back into a select tag, after some other work, with the array as the options using

```
//empty the options and rebuild
            $('#' + id).empty();
            var list = $('#' + id);
            $.each(values, function(key, value) {
                list.append($('<option>', { value: key })
                    .text(value));
            });
```

I am getting each value as a text and each text as text:

```
<option value="0">3</option>
<option value="1">rents</option>
<option value="2">4</option>
<option value="3">other income</option>
```

How can I get it so that the numbers are my values and the text is the text, and not have them all as the text?

```
<option value="3">rents</option>
<option value="4">other income</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are 2 things.

`$.map()` automatically make array flatten... so there is kind of a trick to it ;]

and when you recreate using `each`, `key` stands for index, and actually `value` is your data.

```
id = 1;
var options = $('#' + id + ' option'); //Id of select that is generated dynamically
values = $.map(options, function(option) {
  return [[
    option.value,
    option.text
  ]]; // put it into another array, when flatten you will get list of arrays
});
console.log(values);

// you have list of array like [[1,2],["ads","erere"]]
// thats why value[0] or value[1]        
$('#' + id).empty();
var list = $('#' + id);
$.each(values, function(key, value) {
  list.append($('<option>', { value: value[0] })
              .text(value[1])); 
});
```

Comment: And if OP wants to have `key` and `value` properties on the `values` object they just need to `return { key: option.value, value: option.text }` in `$.map` instead.

Comment: @MattU yes and return it as list of objects(hashes) instead of arrays.  That actually would be more elegant solution